# jquery validation in a codeigniter view doesn't work

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, validation

I  am trying to do jquery validation in a codeigniter view.

when i use "regular form" in the form i named  `name="mytestform"` the validation work but when i use the codeigniter form class that's the form i named `name="mytestform1"` it doesn't work . I can not figure out what is the problem.

this is the code.

```
 <?php

echo "in v_jquery_validation";

?>
<html> 

<!-- 
http://www.camcloud.com/blog/jquery-form-validation-tutorial 
-->
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
</style>    



    </head>

    <body>

    <div style="border-style:solid; border-width:2px;border-color:red;min-height:110px;width:220px;">

                  <?php $attributes = array( 'id' => 'mytestform1','name' => 'mytestform');

        echo form_open('','style="width:200px;min-height:100px;border-style:solid;float:right; border-width:1px;border-color:green;"',$attributes);?>

                      <p>
                       <label for="aname">Name:&nbsp;</label>
                      <input name="aname" size="20" />
                       </p>
                       <p>

                      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                       </p>
        <?php  echo form_close( ); ?>

      </div>

      <div>
      <form id="mytestform" name="mytestform" method="get"  style="width:200px;min-height:100px;border-style:solid;float:left; border-width:1px;border-color:black;"  action="">
                      <p>
                       <label for="aname">Name:&nbsp;</label>
                      <input name="aname" size="20" />
                       </p>
                       <p>

                      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                       </p>
       </form>
</div>

 <script>
$(function() {
   $( "#mytestform" ).validate({
           rules: {
                   aname: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4,
                           maxlength: 20,
                           customvalidation: true
                   }
           },
           messages: {
                   aname: {
                           required: "Dude, enter a name",
                           minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
                           maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
                   }
           }
   });
   $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation",
           function(value, element) {
                   return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
           },
   "Sorry, no special characters allowed"
   );
});


$(function() {
       $( "#mytestform1" ).validate({
               rules: {
                       aname: {
                               required: true,
                               minlength: 4,
                               maxlength: 20,
                               customvalidation: true
                       }
               },
               messages: {
                       aname: {
                               required: "Dude, enter a name",
                               minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
                               maxlength: $.format("Whoa! Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
                       }
               }
       });
       $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation",
               function(value, element) {
                       return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
               },
       "Sorry, no special characters allowed"
       );
    });
</script>


    </body>
```

Maybe the problem is connected with the unusual code i see when i click view source:

```
<body>

    <div style="border-style:solid; border-width:2px;border-color:red;min-height:110px;width:220px;">

                  <form action="http://localhost/hacker_project_v1/c_jquery_validation" style="width:200px;min-height:100px;border-style:solid;float:right; border-width:1px;border-color:green;" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="mytestform1" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="mytestform" />
</div>              
                      <p>
                       <label for="aname">Name:&nbsp;</label>
                      <input name="aname" size="20" class= "required" />
                       </p>
                       <p>

                      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                       </p>
        </form>     
      </div>

      <div>
      <form id="mytestform" name="mytestform" method="get"  style="width:200px;min-height:100px;border-style:solid;float:left; border-width:1px;border-color:black;"  action="">
                      <p>
                       <label for="aname">Name:&nbsp;</label>
                      <input name="aname" size="20" />
                       </p>
                       <p>

                      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                       </p>
       </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if you change form name, you also have to change form name in javascript code.

Comment: I changed it but there is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

your codeigniter code is wrong it should be like this

```
    $attributes = array( 'id' => 'mytestform1','name' => 'mytestform','style'=>'width:200px;min-height:100px;border-style:solid;float:right; border-width:1px;border-color:green;');
    echo form_open('',$attributes);
```

Comment: rajesh kakawat:Thank you very much.You were right and the change you told me to do  solved the problem !!!

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of using jQuery validation consider using the html form validator which is more and more effective then jQuery as you can disable the working of jQuery by disabling the browser javascript.

You only need to have and extra attribute in input field i:e: `required="required"`

[HTML Form Validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)

And for server side validation, CodeIgniter has an awesome library class,

[CodeIgniter Form Validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

The View Part,

```
$this->data['first_name'] = array(
   'name'  => 'first_name',
   'id'    => 'first_name',
   'type'  => 'text',
   'class' => 'textbox',
   'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name', $user->first_name)
);
```

Valiation Part,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required|xss_clean');
```